# How do you pass a path as a parameter to a MySQL query in C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to save the path and filename of an image to a table, but it's not working. The AddParameterWithValue member seems to double all the slashes in the string I am passing and then the ExecuteNonQuery throws an error. I looked everywhere and can't find the solution.

The table is called 'images' and has three columns: id (autoincremented int), path (string), filename (string).

Here is my code:

```
using (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection mySqlConnection = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(Settings.Default.tlConnectionString))
            {
                try
                {
                    mySqlConnection.Open();
                    string cmdText = "INSERT INTO images ('path', 'filename') VALUES (@path, @filename);";
                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdText, mySqlConnection);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@path", @Path.GetDirectoryName(itemFilePath));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@filename", Path.GetFileName(itemFilePath));
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    long imageId = cmd.LastInsertedId;

                    // more code here ...
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
```

The error message I'm getting is this:

> {"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''path', 'filename') VALUES ('\\\\\\\\srvdata\\\\images\\\\products', '8418-(1215608140).' at line 1"}

As you'll notice, it's doubling all the backslashes.

The correct statement should be

> INSERT INTO `myschema`.`images` (`path`, `filename`) VALUES ('\\\\srvdata\\images\\products', '8418-(1215608140).jpg');

Comment: How are you inspecting the result of `Path.GetDirectoryName(itemFilePath)`? If you're inspecting it with your debugger during execution, it might _show_ you a doubling of slashes when that actually means escaped slashes.

Comment: Why are you quoting the column names that you're inserting?

Comment: Why split the path from the filename?  Neither one is of any use without the other

Comment: The error is about using single-quotes around your column names, like `'path', 'filename'`. In SQL, single-quotes are for string literals. MySQL uses back-ticks to delimit identifiers like column names. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql)

Comment: Thanks Bill for pointing that out, you were correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this code and it worked for me. Can you check once more if this works? Only changes here is adding the CommandType as CommandType.Text and Removing the quotes from the command text

```
//Assuming this correct file path
string filePath = @"\\srvdata\images\products\8418-(1215608140).jpg";

using(var mySqlConnection = new MySQl.Data.MySQlClient.MySQlConnection(Settings.Default.tlConnectionString)
{
 try{
  mySqlConnection.Open();
  string commandText = "INSERT INTO images (path, filename) VALUES (@path, @filename);";
  var cmd = new MySqlCommand(commandText, mySqlConnection);
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@path", Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath));
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@filename", Path.GetFileName(filePath));
  int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  if(result!=-1)
  {
   Console.WriteLine("Success");
  }
  else
  {
   throw new Exception("Failure");
  }
 }
 catch(Exception ex)
 {
   Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
 }
 finally
 {
  mySqlConnection.Close();
 }
}
```

Comment: @gunr2171 As you already pointed out, this is the single change that needs to be made to fix the OP's problem. (You could consider adding it as an answer; I'd vote for it.)

Comment: Thanks Revanth, works here too. 